# Magento2 - Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\LayoutUpdate does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, magento2.3.4

While migrating the `Magento` version from `2.3.4` to `2.3.2`.

I am facing below issues while navigating to Product page.

**Error**: `Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\LayoutUpdate does not exist`

In admin panel, when editing the products getting the below error

**Error**: **Product does not exists**"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**The issue is in your database**

I noticed in Magento 2.3.4, they created the `LayoutUpdate` file with the attributes `custom_layout_update_file`.

When we revert back, the attribute calling the file and cause the issue.

solution: Go to your Database and search the table **eav_attribute**

Run below query

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'custom_layout_update_file'
```

You will find two records and just remove them (if you using Magento 2.3.2).

**If you have redis**, you will need to flush the cache from it.

```
redis-cli flushall;
```

Comment: After run the command above, I run this: ```DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'custom_layout_update_file';```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your __constructor Method Objects When You Call That Class.

Run composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento c:f
Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, after clear cache of redis and restart redis, the problem solved, if someone use redis too, you can try this:
redis-cli FLUSHDB – Delete all the keys of the currently selected DB.
redis-cli FLUSHALL – Delete all the keys of all the existing databases, not just the currently selected one.